# From image to numbers

Tags: php, javascript, image-processing, ocr, computer-vision

I have some images that contain numbers written perfectly.
These numbers can go from one to 4 characters.
Is there a way to recognize and convert these numbers to text with PHP or Javascript?

Thank you,

Regards.

Comment: So, you are writing a Captcha Breaker?

Comment: Not really. As I work with CURL, sometimes, I get some phone numbers as images. It would be great if I can convert them ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a go with [this PHPOCR class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html).

Comment: Although if the images are complex, it fails.

Comment: 'Perfectly' written numbers should be ok :p

Comment: After some tests, it returns "Not yet recognized" by running the example file!

Answer (score 2):

Check out this PHP Class!

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html

Good luck :)