# Parse simple numbers from image

Tags: php

So, I have an image like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zWVL.jpg

It always looks like that, although the numbers might differ. It's a gif, the background is transparent, and the numbers white.

I need some way to parse it to numbers to be used in a script. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: This is called [Optical Character Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) (OCR).  It's not a simple task.

Comment: It's OCR, no idea if there are OCR libraries for PHP.  The fact you only have to worry about 10 characters in a set font will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [From image to numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576572/from-image-to-numbers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement OCR on a website using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170271/how-can-i-implement-ocr-on-a-website-using-php)

Comment: In case you want to use a web service, this could be helpful: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/484/are-there-any-online-ocr-services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the font is monospace and the position of the number in the image is constant, it should be trivial to break down the image into individual digits. Then, output each image to some format (PNG is probably best) and compare the files.

This works best if you have the same script save known digits and then compare them to the actual case data. If this is not possible, you will have to do a pixel-for-pixel comparison, which isn't that big of a problem on such small images.

Essentially you're making an extremely primitive OCR by having a program that's along the lines of "this is what the digits look like, so what number is this?"